# Adding Jquery forms validate to vue3

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs3, jquery-steps, jquery-form-validator

I am used to programming on html, css and javascript. I recently learned Vue.js. Is there a way to import jquery form validator and other jquery libraries such as jquery steps to my vue project?

Answer (score 0):

As Vue is using a virtual DOM internally and jQuery is working on the actual DOM in the browser they won't play nice together. That said, you can use jQuery and Vue on the same website as long as you don't modify the DOM elements Vue has ownership over with jQuery and jQuery does not rely on DOM elements that belong to Vue components. There are good Vue libraries to help you, especially regarding validation there is [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/)